# Как из вложенного массива сделать массив объектов по некоторым правилам

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, map

Помогите новичку разобраться)
Есть вложенный массив данных:

```
const data = [['name1','name2'], [2345, 765], [2005, 2301], [1000, 1001], [0.0045, 0.0078], [0.03, 0.02], [0.15, 0.16]]
```

Посути это таблица Excel, где data[0] - названия, data[1...3] - координаты Y, data[4...6] - координаты X для этих названий.
Необходимо получить в итоге массив из 6ти объектов, в которых каждому элементу в data[0] будет соотвествовать 3 раза по 2 пары координат для этих элементов, такого вида:

```
    const result = [
    {
        name: 'name1'
        data: {
            x: 0.0045,
            y: 2345
        }
    },

    {
        name: 'name2'
        data: {
            x: 0.0078,
            y: 765,
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'name1'
        data: {
            x: 0.03,
            y: 2005,
        }
    }, 
    {
        name: 'name2'
        data: {
            x: 0.02,
            y: 2301,
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'name1'
        data: {
            x: 0.15,
            y: 1000,
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'name2'
        data: {
            x: 0.16,
            y: 1001,
        }
    },
]
```

Пробовал таким методом:

```
    const data = [['name1','name2'], [2345, 765], [2005, 2301], [1000, 1001], [0.0045, 0.0078], [0.03, 0.02], [0.15, 0.16]];

const t1 = data[0].map((item, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = item;
  obj.data = {};
  obj.data.x = data[4][index];
  obj.data.y = data[1][index];
  return obj;
})

const t2 = data[0].map((item, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = item;
  obj.data = {};
  obj.data.x = data[5][index];
  obj.data.y = data[2][index];
  return obj;
}) 

const t3 = data[0].map((item, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = item;
  obj.data = {};
  obj.data.x = data[6][index];
  obj.data.y = data[3][index];
  return obj;
}) 

const result = [...t1, ...t2, ...t3]
```

Результат получается, но я никак не учитываю, что первоначальный массив data может быть разной величины, где набор координат может быть намного больше или меньше и повторяю по-сути один и тот же код несколько раз.
Вопрос: Как получить нужный результат одним проходом через map(или любым другим способом), учитывая что первоначальный массив дата может иметь разную длину, с разным набором пар координат для каждого из элементов в data[0]? спасибо!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то наименований может быть много. Первая половина массива - это игреки, вторая половина массива - иксы. Тогда вот такой алгоритм:

```js
const data = [['name1','name2'], [2345, 765], [2005, 2301], [1000, 1001], [0.0045, 0.0078], [0.03, 0.02], [0.15, 0.16]];

// Первый элемент массива - это массив наименований
const names = data.shift();

// Оставшийся массив делим пополам на иксы и игреки
const xs = data.splice(Math.floor(data.length / 2));

// игреки остаются в data, копируем в ys чисто для наглядности
const ys = data;

const result = [];

// перебираем в цикле от 0 до размера xs или ys (они одинаковы по условию задачи)
for (let i=0; i < xs.length; i++) {
  // в каждой итерации перебираем массив наименований, получая наименование и индекс
  names.forEach((name, n) => {
    // добавляем в результат полученный объект
    result.push({
        name: name,
        data: {
          x: xs[i][n],
          y: ys[i][n],
        }
    });
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!!)